# Full and half cycle calculation using simple array

Tags: python, arrays, cycle

My program takes in random array inputs where the array has values of integers from 0-n and the letter "M" which stands for markers. Based on this array I have to determine how many cycles are in the array. The Input are

> [M,1,2,3,4,5,6] = One half cycle
>
> [M,1,2,3,4,5,6,M] = One full cycle
>
> [1,2,3,4,5,M] = One half cycle
>
> [1,2,3,4] = One half cycle
>
> [M, 1,2,3,4] = One half cycle
>
> [M,1,2,3,4,M,6] = One Full and one halfcycle
>
> [M,1,2,3,4,M,6,7,8,M] = Two Full Cycles
>
> [M,1,2,3,4,M,6,7,8,M,M,9] = Two Full Cycles and a half cycle

How can i write code for this sort of logic?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question you need to structure your thoughts.
Let's take your lists and re-arrange it first.

First lest look at the group "One half cycle".

```
[M,1,2,3,4,5,6] = One half cycle
[1,2,3,4,5,M] = One half cycle
[1,2,3,4] = One half cycle
[M, 1,2,3,4] = One half cycle
```

As you can see they share some properties.  They have zero or one M at maximum.  This criterion is enough to identify them.  We will see later how.

The group "one full" has two "M" on the list. Although if the "M" is not the last we need to add "and one halfcycle".

```
[M,1,2,3,4,5,6,M] = One full cycle
[M,1,2,3,4,M,6] = One Full and one halfcycle
```

More than two "M" ends in the "Two full".  Again if the "M" is not the last we need to add "and a half cycle".

```
[M,1,2,3,4,M,6,7,8,M] = Two Full Cycles
[M,1,2,3,4,M,6,7,8,M,M,9] = Two Full Cycles and a half cycle
```

How can we implement this?
We need to count the number of "M" in the various examples.
Given the list:

```
a=["M",1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

you can use:

```
a.count("M")
```

On the list "a" it will return 1.

Now, for all the cases we can write a simple routine. Please read the comments in the code.

```
def find_cycles(alist):
    # we define the events, half, one or two cycle
    ares=["One half cycle", "One full cycle", "Two full cycle"]
    half=" and one half cycle"
    # here we count the number of "M" in the list
    indices = alist.count("M")
    # we define a counter "r" that will be used in "ares"
    r=-1
    # zero or one "M" are the "one half cycle"
    if(indices==0 or indices==1):
        r=0
    # two "M" are the "One full cycle"
    elif(indices==2):
        r=1
    # more than two "M" are "Two full cycle"
    elif(indices>2):
        r=2

    ### BUT we need to check if there is an "halfcycle" more
    ### in the case where there are more than 1 M
    ### to do this we need to check that the last element
    ### in our array is not a "M" and we r should be different than 0
    if(alist[-1]!="M" and r!=0):
        return(ares[r]+half)
    else:
        return(ares[r])
```

Now to test it (note that M needs the quotes):

```
a=["M",1,2,3,4,5,6]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,"M"]
c=[1,2,3,4]
d=["M", 1,2,3,4]
e=["M",1,2,3,4,5,6,"M"]
f=["M",1,2,3,4,"M",6]
g=["M",1,2,3,4,"M",6,7,8,"M"]
h=["M",1,2,3,4,"M",6,7,8,"M","M",9]

all_lists=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]

for i in all_lists:
    print(find_cycles(i))
```

Output:

```
One half cycle
One half cycle
One half cycle
One half cycle
One full cycle
One full cycle and one half cycle
Two full cycle
Two full cycle and one half cycle
```

Take in mind that this works only for the example you gave.  Much more "M" will all end up in "Two full cycles".  From the question, it's unclear if you want to generalize to more than two full cycle.